# Is it okay to have 2 different data structures( Array of Arrays vs array of objects ) to fit the purpose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a workout object and when it comes to rendering the exercises I have 2 cases:

1. An exercise is collection of exercises, AKA "circuit" or "superset".
2. "Regular" single exercise.

When the exercise is a circuit I had to put its sets in **Array of arrays** , because if user wants to delete a set, all sequence should be deleted (A1,B1,C1) otherwise it would mess the flow.

When it's a "regular" exercise I have put my sets in **array of objects**, since it's only 1 exercise the flow would not change upon deletion of a set.

When it comes to rendering I have 2 different components that I check with ternary operator:

```
{exercises.map((exercise) =>
  exercise.type === "superset" ? <RenderCircuit/> : <RenderRegularExercise/>}
```

So far it works, but is there a possibility of bugs when data is stored in a different manner?

Or what would happen if I eventually wanted to release a feature that wouldn't work with that data structure?

[image]

Comment: While it is "okay", it does make things harder on yourself for no apparant reason (checking if is array or object when trying to render, mapping over the items in `exerciseNumber`, etc). What's wrong with having an array with just a single item/exercise in it?

Comment: Let me know if I'm missing something, but if I have a circuit with these sets A1,B1,A2B2,A3,B3, how would I be able to delete a selected pair eg. A2,B2 if they're not paired?